# How to correctly integrate when acceleration is time dependent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

The problem is as follows:
A ball moving in a straight line is experiencing acceleration $a(t)=kt$ until it arrives at a certain length $l$ when some time $t_f$ has passed. The initial speed and position are both $0$

In order to solve this equation I tried using the alternative form $\int v dv = \int a dx$

In which I found the final speed via $\int_{0}^{v_f}v dv=\int_{0}^{l} k t dx$
result being  $\frac{1}{2} {v_f}^2 = l k t_f $

This is wrong.

My questions are:

1.How does one go about integrating acceletarion with respect to position, when acceletarion is time dependant.

2.Why does the aformentioned process work when acceletarion is constant.

Comment: If a=a(t) you have to integrate for t, which you also can do for a=const, but integrating for x when t depends on x does not work-

Comment: From any acceleration, $a(t)$, you will get $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ by integration.  Certainly you will not find that $x$ does not depend on $t$.  But that is what you assumed in your $\int k t \, dx$ integral.  That should be read as $\int_0^\ell k\, t(x) \, dx$ and you need to know the functional form $t(x)$, the inversion of $x(t)$, in order to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the definition of acceleration as first derivative of speed:

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{dv}{dt}.
\end{equation}

Integrating both sides we have

\begin{equation}
\int_0^v dv' = \int_0^t dt'\,a(t')=\int_0^t dt'\,kt'=\frac{kt^2}{2}.
\end{equation}

Hence, the speed is $v(t)=\frac{kt^2}{2}$. Use the definition of speed as first derivative of position

\begin{equation}
v=\frac{dx}{dt},
\end{equation}

and integrate both sides:

\begin{equation}
l=\int_0^l dx = \int_0^{t_f} dt\,v(t)=\int_0^{t_f} dt\,\frac{kt^2}{2}=\frac{kt^3_f}{6}
\end{equation}

from which $t_f^3=\frac{6l}{k}$. Plug now $t_f$ into $v(t_f)$ and you get the final speed as a function of $l$:

\begin{equation}
v_f=\frac{kt^2_f}{2}=\frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{6l}{k}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(6l\sqrt{k}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{equation}

Comment: That last expression should be $\frac 1 2 ( 6 \sqrt{K} L)^{2/3}$

Comment: You are right, I corrected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was aware of this method,  I wanted to know if there is a way to integrate with respect to x something that is time dependant.

Comment: To do an integral with respect to $x$, you would need to know $t(x)$.  But that would mean you've already solved the problem!  See my comment to your original post.

Comment: @Tensritu In other words what you want to do can be done if acceleration is of the form $a(t(x))$ which would be complicated to integrate with the partial derivatives.